# Modbus TCP Little Endian Byte Swop

Tags: .net, modbus-tcp

I am using FluentModbus, have tried EasyModbus also, to communicate with a Delta SE CPU , I can communicate fine as long as I read/ write single registers, problem is I need to convert to Little Endian ByteSwap to access PLC Doubles and Floats, have tested this with ModbussPoll I purchased awhile ago for excel.

Any Idea how I can resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Please tag this with the language you are using (I'm guessing one targeting .NET)

Comment: For EasyModbus take a look at [ConvertRegistersToFloat](https://github.com/rossmann-engineering/EasyModbusTCP.NET/blob/master/EasyModbus/ModbusClient.cs#L254); re FluentModbus it looks like there is some [ongoing work](https://github.com/Apollo3zehn/FluentModbus/issues/27) on this. Unfortunately as this is not covered by the Modbus standard you may need to implement your own solution if the above do not help (the easy modbus source should point you in the right direction).

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your help.

This works

```
var ReadunitIdentifier = (byte)0xFF;
        var ReadstartingAddress = (ushort)40;
        var Readcount = (ushort)4;

       
        if (modbusTcpClient.IsConnected)
        {
            try
            {
                var byteData = modbusTcpClient.ReadHoldingRegisters<byte>(ReadunitIdentifier, ReadstartingAddress, Readcount);
                byte highByte0 = byteData[0];
                byte lowByte0 = byteData[1];
                byte highByte1 = byteData[2];
                byte lowByte1 = byteData[3];
                byte[] doubleBytes =
                {
                    lowByte0, highByte0,lowByte1,highByte1
                };
                SharedVariables.LoadcellScaled = BitConverter.ToInt32(doubleBytes, 0);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since version `v2.1.0` you should be able to provide the byte layout of the server (little-endian vs big-endian):

```cs
var client = new ModbusTcpClient(...);
client.Connect(..., ModbusEndianness.BigEndian);

var value = client.ReadHoldingRegisters<float>(...);
```

With `ModbusEndianness.BigEndian` you tell the client to expect a big-endian server which will make the client to reorder the bytes depending on the client's OS architecture (mostly little-endian).

Comment: Thanks i have it set at LittleEndian but still needed to do the byteswop as well.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough. Please try `ModbusEndianness.BigEndian` to tell the little-endian client that the server uses big-endian byte layout in its Modbus messages. This should remove the necessity to swap the bytes manually.

Answer (score 1):

BEWARE - most of what I read above is confused and confusing.

Modbus commonly uses 'big/little endian' to refer to the order in which it transmits 16-bit chucks of a larger 32-bit ( or in principle bigger ) value.

ALMOST ALL USAGE of Modbus DOES NOT swap bytes within each 16-bit value.

So if you have a hex value 0x33221100 endianess is about which order you send the two register values 0x3322 and 0x1100

Some Modbus s/w packages will support 'byte-swapping' so you can send the 16-bit value 0x3322 as a 16-bit value 0x2233.
This MIGHT have some value if you place the two registers received into x86 memory in adjacent locations - then tell the program to interpret it as a 32-bit integer.

But we managed to work with Modbus peripherals for 15 years before coming across this cockamamie way of doing things.

Now if you are a real geek, and start thinking about the order in which bits and bytes travel up and down a serial bus, you can think yourself into a big black hole. Just leave that out and think in terms of complete 16-bit Modbus register values.

Comment: The Modbus standard specifies big-Endian representation for registers (16 bit values) so those should not be an issue (libraries will sort this out for you). However the standard does not cover larger values so if you need to combine multiple 16 bit registers (e.g. into a 32 bit integer or float) then endianness is definitely important. As most users will be polling a device designed by someone else you have to decode whatever you are given and it's something I regularly run into (e.g. just handled a 32 bit float encoded as CDAB).

Comment: Is this not confusing Byte endianness with Word endianness? Byte endianness would affect how you read a single 16bit register, but word endianness would affect how you read a 32bit value (which, if I understand correctly, is just two 16bit registers)